# Formating date to sql date formate in Swift

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I have a method that converts my SQL date to "MM-dd-yyyy, HH:mm" in swift.  I need to be able to convert this back to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss". This will be in server time and also eastern time zone.

Converting to "MM-dd-yyyy, HH:mm":

```
  static func dateView(_ DateString: String) -> String {
        var returnDate = ""
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        let string = String(DateString)
        if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string) {
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            returnDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        }

    return returnDate
}
```

Trying to convert to "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss":

```
static func dateToSQLDate(_ DateString: String) -> String {
    var returnDate = ""
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"
    let string = String(DateString)
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string) {
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
        //dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
        returnDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }

    return returnDate
}
```

Example would be:

```
var date = "3/10/16, 10:00AM"
dateToSQLDate(date)
Expected Out: 2016-03-10T10:00:00
```

Any ideas to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Add an example as well.

Comment: `"MM-dd-yyyy, HH:mm"` != `"MM/dd/yy HH:mm"`

Comment: What is the timezone of your original string? Is it local time, UTC time or server time?

Comment: It will be server time.

Comment: Edit your post and add it to your question as well as which timezone it corresponds to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date format is wrong.

Compare the string `"3/10/16, 10:00AM"` with the date format `"MM/dd/yy HH:mm"`. There are three issues:

- The comma is missing
- The AM/PM specifier `a` is missing
- 12 hour mode is `hh`

---

```
static func dateToSQLDate(_ string: String) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy, hh:mma"
    guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string) else { return "" }
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static func dateToSQLDate(_ DateString: String) -> String {
    var returnDate = ""
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    let string = String(DateString)
    if let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy HH:mm"
        returnDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    }    
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

    return returnDate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered your question, but a few observations:

1. It is probably prudent to always save your IS8601 timestamp strings in GMT/UTC/Zulu timezone (by setting the `timeZone` of your ISO8601 date string formatters to `TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)`, perhaps adding the `X` qualifier in the string to make it completely unambiguous. It shouldn’t be “server time zone” and probably shouldn’t be the device’s local time zone either.
2. Even better, I might suggest using the `ISO8601DateFormatter` instead, which sets timezones, locales, etc., automatically, making configuration less fragile.
3. I’d suggest instantiating two separate date formatters, one for the ISO 8601 date format (the one with the `T` in it), and another for presenting dates in your UI. While the ISO 8601 date formatter should use the `en_US_POSIX` locale (and if you use `ISO8601DateFormatter`, that’s taken care of for you), the UI date formatter should not (because you presumably want to show the date in the user’s device’s current locale).
4. I personally would suggest that your model objects don’t use a string for the date, but rather use a `Date` object, instead. So, use `ISO8601DateFormatter` when converting between `Date` and API strings, store the `Date` in your model object, and only use the `DateFormatter` with `dateStyle` and `timeStyle` when presenting the `Date` in the user interface.

   So this means that rather than two string-to-string routines, you have string-to-date (and vice versa) for each of the two formatters.
5. Date formatters are notoriously computationally expensive to create. So you might consider creating these two formatters once, save them in ivars, and then you don’t have to repeatedly reinstantiate them.